# Is there any way to run unit tests for swift without having to actually run the application

Tags: swift, unit-testing

Is this just one of those things that enterprise developers need to get used to?

Is there some advantage to every time you run your unit tests the application needs to spin up?

Am I do something so completely wrong that no-one understands this question - googling doesn't seem to provide anyone else moaning about it.

Comment: Generally when you're unit testing, you don't run the actual app, itself. It's just going to run the code that you call from your unit test. Clearly, if you have good "code coverage", you'll be testing most, if not all, of the routines inside the app, but that's very different from "running" the whole app, itself. You may do that in UI testing, but not in unit testing. That having been said, if you unit test an iOS app, it will "spin up" the simulator, but that's not running the app, itself, just running the tests on the simulator.

Comment: Hi Rob, when it "spins up" the simulator it triggers the main method on the application - is that what you would expect to happen or do I configuration set wrong.

Comment: No, that's right. My point is that you're going to be exercising various public methods of your classes, and you won't be running the app through it's entire UI, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jon Reid wrote a good blog post about not running the application when running unit tests: http://qualitycoding.org/app-delegate-for-tests/.

The idea is basically replacing the App Delegate in `main.swift` for an 
"empty" App Delegate when you run the tests target, so you don't run any application logic when running the tests.